# Rails - MongoDB replica set issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, database-replication, failover

I was doing the failover testing of mongodb on my local environment. I have two mongo servers(hostname1, hostname2) and an arbiter.

I have the following configuration in my mongoid.yml file

```
localhost:
  hosts:
  - - hostname1
    - 27017
  - - hostname2
    - 27017
  database: myApp_development
  read: :primary
  use_activesupport_time_zone: true
```

Now when I start my rails application, everything works fine, and the data is read from the primary(hostname1). Then I kill the mongo process of the primary(hostname1), so the secondary(hostname2) becomes the primary and starts serving the data.

Then after some time I start the mongo process of hostname1 then it becomes the secondary in the replica set.
Now the primary(hostname2) and secondary(hostname1) are working all right.

The real problem starts here.

I kill the mongo process of my new primary(hostname2), but this time, the secondary(hostname1) does not become the primary, and any further requests to the rails application raises the following error

```
Cannot connect to a replica set using seeds hostname2
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

** UPDATE: **

I entered some loggers in the mongo repl_connection class, and came across this.

When I boot the rails app, I have both the hosts in the seeds array, that the mongo driver keeps track of. But during the second failover only the host that went down is present in this array.

Hence I would also like to know, how and when one of the hosts get removed from the seed list.

Comment: did you check the logs of hostname1 (original primary) and see why it's not becoming the primary again when hostname2 is killed?  Is the arbiter still up?

Comment: The arbiter is still up, also in the console of the original primary it shows that it has become the PRIMARY, but the seed list maintained by the ruby mongo driver only has the reference of the old primary.

Comment: could be a problem with ruby driver - what version of MongoDB driver are you using?